# tomcat issue with loading page

Tags: java, tomcat, oauth

I've been working off an example (http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html) and I've been debugging some issues and I can't seem to figure this one out:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing OAuthProvider class name in the configuration. Make sure 'com.sun.jersey.config.property.oauth.provider' property is set.
 at com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.OAuthProviderInjectionProvider$1.instance(OAuthProviderInjectionProvider.java:73)
 at com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.OAuthProviderInjectionProvider$1.instance(OAuthProviderInjectionProvider.java:67)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.util.LazyVal.get(LazyVal.java:57)
 at com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.OAuthProviderInjectionProvider.getInjectable(OAuthProviderInjectionProvider.java:114)
 at com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.OAuthProviderInjectionProvider.getInjectable(OAuthProviderInjectionProvider.java:62)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.InjectableProviderFactory.getInjectable(InjectableProviderFactory.java:214)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.InjectableProviderFactory.getInjectableWithScope(InjectableProviderFactory.java:245)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.ServerInjectableProviderFactory.getInjectableiWithScope(ServerInjectableProviderFactory.java:90)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentInjector.processFields(ResourceComponentInjector.java:115)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentInjector.<init>(ResourceComponentInjector.java:93)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.<init>(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:143)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$PerRequest.init(PerRequestFactory.java:174)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$9.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:542)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$9.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:540)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:197)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getResourceComponentProvider(WebApplicationImpl.java:540)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiateResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:615)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiateResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:610)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:155)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1182)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$600(WebApplicationImpl.java:161)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:698)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:197)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:690)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:438)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:287)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:587)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:213)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:342)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:516)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414
```

Comment: Going after exception, you need declare OAuthServerFilter in your config and set com.sun.jersey.config.property.oauth.provider there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it by removing the OAuth jar from the /lib folder.